# My windows 10 applications updating problem

Tags: nokia-lumia-620

Some of my windows phone apps are updating but it is not finished even in 5,6 days...  and some of the new apps also aren't ready to be installed in my windows phone 10 just like viber,messenger,etc. and some other apps...